# Como resolver "the getter data was called on null"?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Fala pessoal!

Estou tentando criar uma função `changeLikes` aonde o meu documento (snapshot) do firebase tem seu `likes` incrementado pelo Firebase ao clicar no `ontap` através do `FieldValue`. Porém, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem "the getter data was called on NUll".

Detalhe, se eu especifico o documento a função funciona, porém não quero especificar o documento. Pois, tem uma lista com vários. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso estar fazendo errado?

```
import 'package:e_ai_casimiro/models/likes_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';


void main() {
runApp(EaiCasimiro());
}

class EaiCasimiro extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return ScopedModel<LikesModel>(
    model: LikesModel(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: "E aí,  Casimiro?",
      home: HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     )
    );
   }
  }  




import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class LikesModel extends Model {

final DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

LikesModel({this.snapshot});

bool _liked = true;

static LikesModel of(BuildContext context) =>
  ScopedModel.of<LikesModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true);


bool isLiked() => _liked;

void pressed(){
_liked = !_liked;
notifyListeners();
}

void  changeLikes() async{

await Firestore.instance
    .collection("lanchonetes")
    .document(snapshot.documentID)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(_liked ? -1 : 1)});

   }
}

class LanchonetesContact extends StatefulWidget {
final DocumentSnapshot lanchonetes;

LanchonetesContact(this.lanchonetes);

@override
_LanchonetesContactState createState() => _LanchonetesContactState();
}

class _LanchonetesContactState extends State<LanchonetesContact> {



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 70.0,
                        width: 390.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ? 
                              Icons.favorite_border : Icons.favorite,
                              color: LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ? 
                              Colors.black : Colors.red,
                              size: 50.0,
                            ),

                            StreamBuilder(
                        stream: Firestore.instance
                               .collection('lanchonetes')
                               .document(widget.lanchonetes.documentID)
                               .snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
                                snapshot.data.data["likes"].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        LikesModel.of(context).pressed();
                        LikesModel.of(context).changeLikes();

                      }

                  ))
         ),
```

Qual me retorna a seguinte informação:

```
════════ (114) Exception caught by widgets library  
═════════════════════════════════════════════════
The getter 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
Row    
file:///Users/ricardooscarkanitz/AndroidStudioProjects/e_ai_casimiro/lib/contacts/lanchonetes_contact.dart:79:36
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Talvez o teu `document` não esteja retornando nenhum registro para o `documentId` informado... Nos informe em que momento está dando o erro

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro acredito que seja no documentId mesmo, se eu digito o nome do documento específico a função funciona, o meu snapshot não está chamando o Firestore, infelizmente sou iniciante no flutter e nao sei como resolver.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e nos informe algumas coisas: Onde você faz uso do método `changeLikes()`? De onde vem o `FieldValue`? Debugue seu método `changeLikes()` e nos mostre o que vem no `snapshot`?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro o ```changeLikes``` é usado na função ```onTap```, o ```FieldValue```é usado para incrementar um valor no Firebase, no ```snapshot```deveria acessar os documentos da minha coleção ```lanchonetes```assim como na minha classe ```LanchonetesContact```, porém acredito que não esteja acessando o documento por algum motivo.

Comment: Eu vi que modificou sua pergunta, assim que possível crio uma resposta pra ti!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está instânciando seu `LikesModel` dentro de seu `ScopedModel` mas não está passando o snapshot para o model, então quando você tenta acessá-lo vai dar o erro que está recebendo...

Abaixo deixo uma forma de correção, não entendo muito de `ScopedModel` mas daí tu implementa o que faltar.

> Na sua classe `LikesModel` faça:

```
class LikesModel extends Model {

bool _liked = true;

static LikesModel of(BuildContext context) =>
  ScopedModel.of<LikesModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true);


bool isLiked() => _liked;

void pressed(){
  _liked = !_liked;
  notifyListeners();
}

void  changeLikes(String docummentId) async{

await Firestore.instance
    .collection("lanchonetes")
    .document(docummentId)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(_liked ? -1 : 1)});

   }
}
```

Como de início você não terá acesso ao `DocumentSnapshot` não é necessário passar ele na criação de sua classe.

> Na sua view faça:

```
class LanchonetesContact extends StatefulWidget {
final DocumentSnapshot lanchonetes;

LanchonetesContact(this.lanchonetes);

@override
_LanchonetesContactState createState() => _LanchonetesContactState();
}

class _LanchonetesContactState extends State<LanchonetesContact> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 1.0,
        child: GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              height: 70.0,
              width: 390.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ? 
                    Icons.favorite_border : Icons.favorite,
                    color: LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ? 
                    Colors.black : Colors.red,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('lanchonetes')
                      .document(widget.lanchonetes.documentID)
                      .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
                      snapshot.data.data["likes"].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
                    )
                  )
                ],
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              LikesModel.of(context).pressed();
              LikesModel.of(context).changeLikes(widget.lanchonetes.documentID);
            }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Dessa forma, você passa o `documentID` para o seu método que fará o update!

**DICA**

Tente não trabalhar diretamente com o snapshot, tente abstrair em classes e trabalhar em cima delas, use o `snapshot` apenas para iniciar suas classes, fica mais simples de entender e trabalhar.

Comment: Valeu Matheus, pesquisei várias maneiras mas nenhuma chegou perto. Obrigado pela dica sobre o snapshot.